# Escaping a href

Tags: php, html

How do I properly escape a href properly in my html anchor tag link and still be able to retrieve the data I send through the url for use in the next page.
My code looks like this:

```
<a href='course.php?id=".encrypt($courseid)."'>".$result->row('title')."</a>
```

Comment: [urlencode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php)

Answer (score 2):

You need to URL-encode the value to preserve URL-syntax, and since you're putting that URL into HTML you should HTML-encode it too:

```
printf('<a href="course.php?id=%s">%s</a>',
       htmlspecialchars(rawurlencode($courseid)),
       htmlspecialchars($result->row('title')));
```

See http://php.net/htmlspecialchars, http://php.net/rawurlencode, http://php.net/printf.

On the other side the value will be available in `$_GET['id']` (you do not need to decode it in any way there).

Comment: am using this link within the html table and I need something that I can still use within the td tags without necessarily doing the printf. Full code looks like this;
<td style='$style'><a href='course.php?id=".encrypt($courseid)."'>".$result->row('title')."</a></td>";

Comment: You can do the same with string concatenation too. You don't require `printf`. This is just used in this example to make it more readable.

Comment: this doesnt seem to work in my code. it seems to be breaking up my code as the id is not being sent through. How would you advice me to escape it using the backslashes (\)

Comment: *Don't.* Backslashes has nothing to do here. Read [The Great Escapism (Or: What You Need To Know To Work With Text Within Text)](http://kunststube.net/escapism/).

Comment: how would I be able to do as you advised in a html table without breaking up my code since as of now it seems like the solution you provided is not working; here is my structure: <td><a href='course.php?id=".encrypt($courseid)."'>".$result->row('title')."</a></td>